# Meaning of pedestrian

Tags: word-meaning

The dictionary meaning of pedestrian is someone who walks by foot. But in these sentences I'm not sure what the meaning is. Can someone help me understand the meaning of the word **pedestrian** here.

1. He lived a **pedestrian** life, working at the paper mill and living in his trailer.
2. Once Acharya was pointing out that you first have to satisfy your material needs before you can start thinking about things transcendental. But, being a more **pedestrian** sort, I apply it to more down-to earth contexts.

Comment: There is more than one dictionary meaning of *pedestrian*.

Answer (score 2):

Pedestrian has two dictionary meanings:

> NOUN A person walking rather than travelling in a vehicle.
>
> ‘the road is so dangerous pedestrians avoid it’
>   as modifier ‘a pedestrian bridge’
>
> ADJECTIVE Lacking inspiration or excitement; dull.
>
> ‘disenchantment with their pedestrian lives’

The adjective meaning arose because walking somewhere is slower, and duller, than e.g. riding on a horse, or (later) in a motor vehicle, train, etc.

[Pedestrian (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pedestrian)